# Correct StackOverflow domain but suspicious TLD

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

So I was browsing on Google for some query regarding X-Unit test cases, where I bumped into stack overflow site as shown in Screenshot. When the page opened I was logged out!? Contrarily I was logged into SO already in the next immediate Chrome's tab. Then I noticed the Url of the site I opened, and that caused little suspicion. The domain is SO, UI feel is SO's but TLD is `.com.mevn.net`

So what exactly is `mevn.net`? It does not show 'https' certificate, neither it has cookies that logs me in automatically like authentic SO site. And most importantly why such URL is in top 10 result of Google Search?

[image: SO TLD]

Comment: How can other service scraping sites have same domain as of SO? I went through other questions, where SO domain is not taken...Here the entire SO domain is copied? Is it still duplicate?

Comment: @KaranDesai It's a subdomain of `mevn.net`.  Just like we are on meta.stackoverflow.com (where meta is the subdomain), you can create any subdomain you want on your domain.  They did it to confuse people and make them think they are on the real stack overflow... but it's not the real site.  I'd steer clear. :)

Comment: Ohh okay that's what I wanted to confirm that it is indeed not SO site. Very dangerous:  it appeared in Google top 10 search result. Will report this on SO Contact Us Form.